# I want to kill ,all the running process with name folder=work14 through pid

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

sudo kill -15 `ps aux | grep "folder=work14 stdbuf"| grep -v grep|awk '{print $2}' |tr "\n" " "`

but this above gives me error

kill: failed to parse argument: '28769 28781 28790 28802 '

Comment: You can't just use [killall](https://linux.die.net/man/1/killall)?

Comment: it work for me when only one pid is present ,when multiple pid its gives me error   kill: failed to parse argument: '28769 28781 28790 28802 ' @kaylum

Comment: `killall` is a different command to `kill`. Read the linked man page.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`xArgs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) to *forward* all the pid's to the `kill` command:

```sh
sudo ps -A | grep "folder=work14 stdbuf" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -15 $1
```

For more information, take a look at: [How to kill all proccess with a given name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316065/how-to-kill-all-process-with-given-name)

---

As @kaylum suggested, using [`killall`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/killall) would be a cleaner solution if all the processes have the same name

Comment: *kill accepts just one pid to kill* that's incorrect, please remove that from your answer

Comment: what about kill -9 pid1 pid2 pid3

Comment: Sorry, didn't formulate it correct, what I ment was that kill won't understand multiple pids if there aren't space delimited, eg: `kill -9 'pid1 pid2 pid3'` wont work, but `kill -9 pid1 pid2 pid3` will work!

Comment: @maddy "not working" Could you elaborate? Working on my machine...

Comment: @0stone0 im runnign script someting like that " sudo  PYTHON_ENV=dev folder=work14 stdbuf -oL python xyzzzz.py " so that ` ps -A ` not working for me